# using tensorflow in Pycharm

Tags: tensorflow, pycharm, tensorflow-serving, tensor

Anyone have a solution for using tensorflow in Pycharm and getting the following warnings:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/base.py:198: retry (from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.base) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use the retry module or similar alternatives.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/dwilliams/Desktop/EBIMNIST/main.py:8: read_data_sets (from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.mnist) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please use alternatives such as official/mnist/dataset.py from tensorflow/models.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py:260: maybe_download (from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.base) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please write your own downloading logic.
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the `base.py`file at `tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.base`.

You are using some of the tensorflow code for downloading data files from internet. Tensorflow wants to remove the code so they are warning you to write your own code.

Just use below code instead of `maybe_download()`:

```
 from six.moves import urllib
 urllib.request.urlretrieve(download_file_url, file_path)
```